# How do I know when it is time to switch to doing a read operation from a MySQL query to Redis?

Tags: mysql, caching, redis

**Versions**:
I'm using MySQL 5.6 and considering also using Redis 3.0 (to help with a growing diverse set of reads, a.k.a "screens"). I'm currently using a single server, however with Redis I suppose I could eventually cluster in more Redis servers later if needed.

**Current Situation:**
The only slowness I've encountered in my read queries so far was due to needing more indexes or slow UNIONs. So I added more indexes, and I  carefully condensed some data into single tables to eliminate most of the problem UNIONs (reducing some JOINs, however I still use JOINs frequently and so far they are not a problem).

**The Question:**
I'm going through a re-factoring of my app and I'm nicely separating out all my read queries (CQRS). While I'm doing this, I wanted to know if it is the right time to consider replacing many of the read queries with Redis. It would remove the need to have a significant amount of indexes I'm using on tables I write to (which will free up more RAM). Of course I'll keep the core tables for writing to, but my data will grow because now I'll have new Redis tables for almost every read query (ie. UI screen/view). This in turn will take away more RAM. How do I know when it's time to start switching over to Redis? What's the procedure for determining this or preparing for this? Obviously I don't want to be guilty of "premature optimization", but I don't want to avoid caching and it come back to bite me later. I hope the answer is not "do something when everything slows down", but I don't want to force myself into needing an additional Redis cluster server prematurely (by eating up all the RAM on my current server with all the added Redis denormalized data).

Comment: Moving your read queries to Redis could be a non trivial effort, but if you expect growth and need for performance, the earlier the better imo. Also, don't run your MySQL and Redis databases on the same server - doing this is a sure way to get into trouble.

Comment: Ok, so it seems the answer is to ensure I'm ready to substitute my queries with calls from Redis on another server. I suppose I'll have to find a way to monitor performance in MySQL, and when I feel the time is right to stop adding RAM and instead add a second server, then Redis will help.

Comment: @ItamarHaber you can put all that into an answer and I can accept it. Thx

Comment: Cool, but I feel I owe you more info if that's an answer, so feel free to expand your question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving your read queries to Redis could be a non trivial effort, but if you expect growth and need for performance, the earlier the better imo.

Also, don't run your MySQL and Redis databases on the same server - doing this is a sure way to get into trouble.